# finding integrals by parts

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\int^{1}_{0} x^2(x+1)^5 dx$$

I would appreciate if you could go through the process step by step. I have been working on this problem for quite awhile and cannot seem to figure it out.

after finding the $u, du, dv, v$ my equation is

$\frac{x^2(x+1)^6}{6}-$ $\int^{1}_{0} \frac{ (x+1)^6}{6 (2x)}dx$

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You're on the right track. You just need to do integration by parts one more time with that second integral, then you'll be left with a third integral you can solve without integration by parts. (To make your work a bit more organized, you should try the tabular method)

Comment: @user149420 is that what you wanted to write?

Answer (score 1):

Your first part is correct, your second is not.  It should be

$$\int vdu=\int\frac{(x+1)^6}62xdx$$

Another round of integration by parts will eliminate that last $x$.  However, it's probably a lot easier to solve the problem without integration by parts.  Just a simple substitution

$$u=x+1,du=dx$$
$$\int_1^2(u-1)^2u^5du=\int_1^2u^7-2u^6+u^5du$$

Answer (score 0):

Do integration by parts one more time.

$$\int x^2(x+1)^5\ dx \\
= x^2\cdot\frac16(x+1)^6-\int2x\cdot\frac16(x+1)^6\ dx \\
= x^2\cdot\frac16(x+1)^6-2x\cdot\frac1{42}(x+1)^7+\int\frac1{21}(x+1)^7\ dx
$$